# When one's surface flat, then below has a hole

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> When one's surface flat, then below has a hole
>   Where fallen leaves may endlessly patrol
>   Like a witches hat, standing on end
>   Deep space cousin causes time to bend
>   From many things together must go
>   Submerged travel agent of Toto

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a description of a

> whirlpool, perhaps in a swimming pool.

When one's surface flat, then below has a hole
Where fallen leaves may endlessly patrol

> Sounds like a reasonable description of a (currently unused) swimming pool. Could be a pond or lake instead, but they'd be less likely to have a drain.

Like a witches hat, standing on end

> This is approximately the shape of (the "air" portion of) a whirlpool.

Deep space cousin causes time to bend

> A spinning black hole has some similar properties, and the traditional rubber-sheet representation of a two-dimensional version will have a similar shape.

From many things together must go

> I don't have a good explanation for this line.

Submerged travel agent of Toto

> A whirlpool is like an underwater version of a tornado, as seen e.g. in *The Wizard of Oz*. (Toto is Dorothy's dog.)

Comment: I think you got it!

Comment: Apparently there isn't universal agreement about this :-).

Comment: The toto line really narrows it down

Comment: Will had a comment earlier saying he thought it should be something broader, and posted an answer which he's now deleted. If the intended answer turns out to be something strictly more general than my answer (which it might well do), let the record show that Will got there first.